# How to Show incoming call notification for Agora 1 to 1 video call app

Tags: android, agora.io

Since Agora works by creating a channel how can one show the other user that there is a call for . 
One way I thought was by creating a service that will listen to the **server** using retrofit and if there is a change in status of the call I will show it to him but in android background services are restricted.
Another way I thought was by creating a broadcast receiver with a scheduler. Can Any One Help in this.

```
class CallReciever : BroadcastReceiver() {
    val REQUEST_CODE : Int= 12345
    val ACTION :String= "com.codepath.example.servicesdemo.alarm"
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val i = Intent(context, MyTestService::class.java)
        startWakefulService(context, i)
    }
}
```

```
class MyTestService : IntentService("MyTestService") {

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        // Do the task here
       getBanner()
    }
    private fun getBanner() {

        val service = RetrofitCall.provideRetrofit().create(callrecieveAPI::class.java)
        val call = service.banner()

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<CallReceivePOJO> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<CallReceivePOJO>, response: Response<CallReceivePOJO>) {
                //showFailureDialog(GuestCheckoutActivity.this, response.body().getMessage());

                CommonObjects.channelid =response.body()!!.data.toString()

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<CallReceivePOJO>, t: Throwable) {
                // handle execution failures like no internet connectivity

            }
        })

    }
}
```

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        scheduleAlarm()
        object : CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
            override fun onFinish() { 
                     intent = Intent(applicationContext, VideoChatViewActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)

            }

            override fun onTick(p0: Long) {}
        }.start()
    }


    fun scheduleAlarm() {
        // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, CallReciever::class.java)
        // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
        val pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
        // Setup periodic alarm every every half hour from this point onwards
        val firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() // alarm is set right away
        val alarm = this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
        // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
            10000, pIntent
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Agora has a few sample apps that show how to achieve a "call" functionality using Agora's Video and Real-Time Messaging SDKs along with the native APIs *(Android's ConnectionService and iOS's CallKit)*.

Android: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Video-Calling/tree/master/OpenDuo-Android

IOS: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Video-Calling/tree/master/OpenDuo-iOS

Comment: For flutter tutorial : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323490/989418

Comment: for android tutorial link, it will show this error https://prnt.sc/sqm20e , as `libs/agora-rtm-sdk.jar` does not exist.

Comment: did you add in the libraries? the demos don't normally contain the sdk itself.